# Stuck with Javascript array , node

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am very new at javascript/node and I am stuck at a question in which I have to find prime numbers. I think my logic is correct but it is producing extra numbers. Here is code 
For now I am using array from 2 to 100. Thank you In advance

```
var num = [2];
for (var i = 3; i < 101; i++){
  num.push(i);
}

for(i = 0; i <= num.length; i++){
  for(var k = 2; k <= i; k++){
    if( (num[i] % k) == 0){
      num.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}

var fs = require('fs');
var outfile = "hel.txt";
fs.writeFileSync(outfile, num);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The satement *"but it is producing extra numbers"* is not quite correct. You produced the array containing all numbers up to 100 at the beginning. The problem is that not all non-prime numbers are removed.

Why? Because you are modifying the array while you are iterating over it. The consequence is that some entries won't be checked, they will be skipped.

Example:

Imagine the array

```
var num = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
```

Let `i` be `7`, so we are testing `num[7] = 9`. `9` is not prime so it is removed from the array, which then looks like

```
var num = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,11];
```

In the next iteration `i` is `8` and we are testing `num[8] = 11`. Notice how `10` was not tested? Originally `10` was at index `8` but since we removed `9`, its new index is `7`, which we already tested. The size of the array changed and all elements "to right of" `9` have been moved one position to the left.

---

To solve this, you can iterate over the array in *reverse order* (I also think `k <= i` should be `k < num[i]`):

```
for (i = num.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
  var n = num[i];
  for (var k = 2; k < n; k++) {
    if ((n % k) == 0) {
      num.splice(i, 1);
      break; // you can stop testing after you found a factor
    }
  }
}
```

Small suggestion to your algorithm: It is enough to only test factors up to the square root of the number, i.e.:

```
for (var k = 2, r = Math.sqrt(n); k <= r; k++) {
    if ((n % k) == 0) {
      num.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    }
}
```

There are probably other possible improvements as well,  have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes.

Comment: Hacky solution to his code would be  `if( (num[i] % k) == 0){   num.splice(i, 1);i--;}`

Comment: @Bhanu423: There were some errors in the code, but I fixed them now.

Comment: Was about to comment that out anyways it works now . anyways can you tell what was wrong in your old solution . Thanks in advance

Comment: @Bhanu423: I changed `k <= i` to `k <= num[i]` but this will ultimately compute `num[i] % num[i]` which is of course `0`. So all numbers were removed from the array. Your approach (`k <= i`) only worked because the index of the array is different than the value at that index (i.e. `a[2] = 4` not `a[2] = 2`). Otherwise you would have encountered that problem as well. Still, iterating from `2` up to the loop index of the outer loop (your way) didn't seem to be correct either (overall). For an efficient algorithm, have a look at the Wikipedia link anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 for(i = num.length; i >= 0; i--){
    findFactors: for(var k =2; k <= i; k++){
        if(num[i]%k ==0){
             num.splice(i,1);
             break findFactors;
        }
    }
```

I haven't tested it so not sure if it works...

Comment: It works too . ANyways I upvoted the other answer as his code was more closer to mine . Anyways don't have the repo to upvote you so cudn't. anyways thanks for the answer